# Automating creation of APIs in API manager

Tags: azure-api-management

Is there a way to add APIs in an automated fashion to the API manager? For example, if I have various service fabric apps with Open API/Swagger definitions and want to update the API manager during CI/CD, is there a practical way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If this is really about Azure API Management service, then yes, we have:

- ARM templates
- Management API
- Git

to support your automation scenarios.

Comment: Yes but if I have a dev and prod azure API manager and wanted to push certain API products between dev and prod, how would I do this?

Comment: You either maintain them in ARM template and then deploy this template first into your dev service, test, and then into prod service. That may be cumbersome.
You may user our API and build automation yourself using whatever tools necessary.
Or you may look into our Git integration. That would allow you to dump APIM configuration into Git repository, and deploy configuration from there as well.

Comment: Have you checked out this project http://mlogdberg.com/apimanagement/arm-template-creator